# When is Rspec true != true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec3

I'm going through Hartl's RoR tutorial, and in the rspec test there's a block to check if the passwords match. In this block is this line:

```
     expect(@user.has_password?(@attr[:password])).to be_true
```

which fails. But I know the code works because if I put the line:

```
puts @user.has_password?(@attr[:password])
```

in the block it outputs "true." What really throws me is that I put the line:

```
     expect(true).to be_true
```

in place of the line above... and the test STILL FAILS. What's up with that?

Comment: Don't know why it fails but try `expect(true).to be true` (without underscore) and see if the result changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `be_true` was renamed to `be_truthy`. Try one of these variants:

```
expect(true).to be true
expect(true).to be_truthy
```

The first one will work only for `true`.
The second for anything that's not `false` or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I tested variants:
expect(true).to be_true # fails
expect(true).to be_truthy # passes
expect(true).to be true # passes
expect(true).to be truthy# undefined local variable or method `truthy'

Also came across this page: http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/01/17/2674/rspec-be-true-be_true-are-different

Comment: Indeed, `be_true` was [deprecated](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283) in rspec3.